# How to enable SSO between Maximo Anywhere apps

Tags: maximo-anywhere

In a scenario where a single user has more than one Maximo Anywhere app installed on his device (eg. Asset Data Manager and Inspection), how to implement device single sign on?.  What I mean is, If user gets authenticated in Inspection, and would like to open AssetDataManager he should be able to get into it without requiring to login again.
Assumption here is that user belongs to both the security groups.

I have gone through the OSLCGenericAdapterImpl.js.  There is a function defined called _setSSOHeaders(headers)
How to leverage this function to implement SSO across two applications.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by using the simple data sharing feature..

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_simple_data_sharing.html

But will require javascript customization to take this shared sessionid, or username/password and send it along from the new application.